# What is the maximum depth of the java call stack?

Tags: java

How deep do I need to go into the call stack before I get a StackOverflowError? Is the answer platform dependent?

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794227/how-to-know-about-outofmemory-or-stackoverflow-errors-ahead-of-time

Comment: Since this is a good question, I've updated the title to something I feel is more clearly associated with the meaning.  (Previously I thought you might be referring to the depth of a *particular* stack you'd captured at runtime, for example).  Feel free to change it back if you disagree.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It depends on the amount of virtual memory allocated to the stack.

http://www.odi.ch/weblog/posting.php?posting=411

You can tune this with the `-Xss` VM parameter or with the `Thread(ThreadGroup, Runnable, String, long)` constructor.

Comment: And perhaps the size of the stack frames you're putting on it?

Comment: The limit also depends on the stack usage in the function.

Comment: if we don't mention the Xss, then?

Answer (score 33):

I tested on my system and didn't find any constant value, sometimes stack overflow occurs after 8900 calls, sometimes only after 7700, random numbers.

```
public class MainClass {

    private static long depth=0L;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        deep(); 
    }

    private static void deep(){
        System.err.println(++depth);
        deep();
    }

}
```

Comment: Isn't it the case that this is tail recursive and shouldn't ever overflow?    Edit: Sorry.  In Java it crashed at 8027;  in Scala it got up to 8594755 before I got bored.

Comment: @arya an important part of the JVM semantics is that tail recursion is not supported.  This gives a lot of interesting problems for those who want to implement languages with tail recursion on the JVM.

Comment: `public foo() { try { foo(); } finally { foo(); } }`
can run 'virtually' forever, in java only though.

Comment: for me, `StackOverflowError` occurs after after 8792

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen tail recursion **optimisation** is not supported. Rather obviously you can have tail recursion. It just doesn't optimise it to not grow the call stack.

Comment: @slim Of course, or it wouldn't be interesting.  Feel free to write a full answer explaining this in detail.

Answer (score 20):

The stack size can be set with the `-Xss` command line switch but as a rule of thumb, it is deep enough, hundreds if not thousands of calls deep. (The default is platform dependent, but at least 256k in most platforms.)

If you get a stack overflow, 99% of the time it's caused by an error in the code.

Comment: +1 for second paragraph. One should always remember about that.

Comment: Using eclipse, I only get 1024 recursive calls.

Comment: @Norswap Are you determining that by the size of the stack trace? That appears to be limited to 1024 regardless of the actual size of the stack.

Answer (score 4):

Compare these two calls:
(1) Static method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 14400; 
    while(true){   
        int myResult = testRecursion(i);
        System.out.println(myResult);
        i++;
    }
}

public static int testRecursion(int number) {
    if (number == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        int result = 1 + testRecursion(number - 1);
        return result;
    }    
}
 //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError after 62844
```

(2) Non-static method using a different class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 14400;
    while(true){       
        TestRecursion tr = new TestRecursion ();
        int myResult = tr.testRecursion(i);
        System.out.println(myResult);
        i++;
    }
} 
//Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError after 14002
```

Test recursion class has `public int testRecursion(int number) {` as the only method.

Answer (score 0):

While traversing a tree with huge depth, we could face this

```
/**
 * -Xss10M
 * max call stack count 92766
 * -Xss100M
 * max call stack count 2148286
 */
public class MaxCallStack {
    private Integer stackCount = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MaxCallStack maxStack = new MaxCallStack();
        maxStack.evaluate();
    }

    private void evaluate() {
        try {
            Tree tree = new Tree();
            tree.left = tree;
            traverse(tree);
        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            System.out.println(String.format("max call stack count %s", stackCount));
        }
    }

    private void traverse(Tree tree) {
        stackCount++;
        if (tree.left != null) {
            traverse(tree.left);
        }
        if (tree.right != null) {
            traverse(tree.right);
        }
    }

    private class Tree {
        Tree left;
        Tree right;
    }
}
```