# Algorithm Efficiency Pattern Matching, Checking for image inside image

Tags: java, algorithm, image-processing, graphics, pattern-matching

This is a more descriptive version of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050383/algorithm-complexity-and-efficiency-exponential-operation-java?noredirect=1#comment37158877_24050383). The problem I am trying to solve relates to block-matching or image-within-image recognition.

I see an image, extract the [x,y] of every black pixel and create a set for that image, such as

```
{[8,0], [9,0], [11,0]}
```

The set is then augmented so that the first pixel in the set is at [0,0], but the relationship of the pixels is preserved. For example, I see {[8,0], [9,0]} and change the set to {[0,0], [1,0]}. The point of the extraction is that now if I see {[4,0], [5,0]}, I can recognize that basic relationship as two vertically adjacent pixels, my {[0,0], [1,0]}, since it is the same image but only in a different location.

I have a list of these pixel sets, called "seen images". Each 'seen image' has a unique identifier, that allows it to be used as a nested component of other sets. For example:

```
{[0,0], [1,0]} has the identifier 'Z'
```

So if I see:

```
{[0,0], [1, 0], [5,6]}
```

I can identify and store it as:

```
{[z], [5, 6]}
```

The problem with this is that I have to generate every combination of [x,y]'s within the pixel set to check for a pattern match, and to build the best representation. Using the previous example, I have to check:

```
{[0,0], [1,0]}, 
{[0,0], [5,6]}, 
{[1,0], [5,6]} which is {[0,0], [4,5]} 
{[0,0], [1,0], [5,6]}
```

And then if a match occurs, that subset gets replaced with it's ID, merged with the remainder of the original set, and the new combination needs to be checked if it is a 'seen image':

```
{[z],[5, 6]}
```

The point of all that is to match as many of the [x,y]'s possible, using the fewest pre-existing pieces as components, to represent a newly seen image concisely. The greedy solution to get the component that matches the largest subset is not the right one. Complexity arises in generating all of the combinations that I need to check, and then the combinations that spawn from finding a match, meaning that if some match and swap produces {[z], [1,0], [2,0]}, then I need to check (and if matched, repeat the process):

```
{[z], [1,0]}
{[z], [2,0]}
{[1,0], [2,0]} which is {[0,0], [1,0]}
{[z], [1,0], [2,0]}
```

Currently I generate the pixel combinations this way (here I use numbers to represent pixels 1 == [x,y]) Ex. (1, 2, 3, 4): Make 3 lists:

```
1.)   2.)   3.)
12    23    34
13    24
14
```

Then for each number, for each list starting at that number index + 1, concatenate the number and each item and store on the appropriate list, ex. (1+23) = 123, (1+24) = 124

```
1.)   2.)   3.)
12    23    34
13    24
14  
----  ----  ----
123   234
124   
134
```

So those are all the combinations I need to check if they are in my 'seen images'. This is a bad way to do this whole process. I have considered different variations / optimizations, including once the second half of a list has been generated (below the ----), check every item on the list for matches, and then destroy the list to save space, and then continue generating combinations. Another option would be to generate a single combination, and then check it for a match, and somehow index the combinations so you know which one to generate next.

Does anyone recognize this process in general? Can you help me optimize what I am doing for a set of ~million items. I also have not yet come up with a non-recursive or efficient way to handle that each match generates additional combinations to check.

Comment: Is this question essentially the same problem as your previous one?  If so, you should edit that question, rather than posting a duplicate...

Comment: I will delete the old one if that helps

Comment: Hmmm, that kind of pattern matching does require considering all combinations. However, you can reduce the block size to greatly speed up the algorithm. IE: Use k x k sized blocks instead of 1x1 pixels. Another route might be to use edge detection. Overall though, it seems your attempt at pattern matching may be too broad. You might want to consider what kinds of patterns are you looking for. You also might want to consider finding k-sized convex hulls within the image which can be done in O(k*N^2). Again, depends on what kinds of patterns you are looking for.