# Selection and Quick Sort will not work

Tags: java, sorting, selection, quicksort

I am creating a program that compares many sorts and the time it takes to complete each one to the other sorts.  I am having issues with the selection and quick sort.  Below is the selection sort code:

```
public class SelectionSort {
    public static void SelectionSort(int[] list) {
        Selection(list, 0, list.length - 1); // Sort the entire list
    }

    public static void Selection(int[] list, int low, int high) {
        if (low < high) {
            // Find the smallest number and its index in list(low .. high)
            int indexOfMin = low;
            int min = list[low];
            for (int i = low + 1; i <= high; i++) {
                if (list[i] < min) {
                    min = list[i];
                    indexOfMin = i;
                }
            }

            // Swap the smallest in list(low .. high) with list(low)
            list[indexOfMin] = list[low];
            list[low] = min;

            // Sort the remaining list(low+1 .. high)
          //  Selection(list, (low + 1), high);
        }
    }


}
```

The very last line will not work in my program.  I am not sure why.

Here is the main code:

```
public Main()
    {

        Integer[] randH = new Integer[50000];
        int i=0;
        while (i < randH.length)
        {randH[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 50000);
            i++;}

        Integer[] randH2 = new Integer[100000];
        i=0;
        while (i < randH2.length)
        {randH2[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100000);
            i++;}

        Integer[] randH3 = new Integer[150000];
        i=0;
        while (i < randH3.length)
        {randH3[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 150000);
            i++;}

        Integer[] randH4 = new Integer[200000];
        i=0;
        while (i < randH4.length)
        {randH4[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 200000);
            i++;}

        Integer[] randH5 = new Integer[250000];
        i=0;
        while (i < randH5.length)
        {randH5[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 250000);
            i++;}

        Integer[] randH6 = new Integer[300000];
        i=0;
        while (i < randH6.length)
        {randH6[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 300000);
            i++;}

        int[] rand = new int[50000];
        i=0;
        while (i < rand.length)
        {rand[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 50000);
            i++;}

        int[] rand1 = new int[100000];
        i=0;
        while (i < rand1.length)
        {rand1[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100000);
            i++;}

        int[] rand2 = new int[150000];
        i=0;
        while (i < rand2.length)
        {rand2[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 150000);
            i++;}

        int[] rand3 = new int[200000];
        i=0;
        while (i < rand3.length)
        {rand3[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 200000);
            i++;}

        int[] rand4 = new int[250000];
        i=0;
        while (i < rand4.length)
        {rand4[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 250000);
            i++;}

        int[] rand5 = new int[300000];
        i=0;
        while (i < rand5.length)
        {rand5[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 300000);
            i++;}

        //Bubble Sort

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        new BubbleSort(rand);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime = endTime - startTime;

        long startTime1B = System.currentTimeMillis();
        new BubbleSort(rand1);
        long endTime1B = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime1B = endTime1B - startTime1B;

        long startTime2B = System.currentTimeMillis();
        new BubbleSort(rand2);
        long endTime2B = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime2B = endTime2B - startTime2B;

        long startTime3B = System.currentTimeMillis();
        new BubbleSort(rand3);
        long endTime3B = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime3B = endTime3B - startTime3B;

        long startTime4B = System.currentTimeMillis();
        new BubbleSort(rand4);
        long endTime4B = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime4B = endTime4B - startTime4B;

        long startTime5B = System.currentTimeMillis();
        new BubbleSort(rand5);
        long endTime5B = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime5B = endTime5B - startTime5B;

        //Selection Sort

        long startTime1S = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SelectionSort.SelectionSort(rand);
        long endTime1S = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime1S = endTime1S - startTime1S;

        long startTime2S = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SelectionSort.SelectionSort(rand1);
        long endTime2S = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime2S = endTime2S - startTime2S;

        long startTime3S = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SelectionSort.SelectionSort(rand2);
        long endTime3S = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime3S = endTime3S - startTime3S;

        long startTime4S = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SelectionSort.SelectionSort(rand3);
        long endTime4S = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime4S = endTime4S - startTime4S;

        long startTime5S = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SelectionSort.SelectionSort(rand4);
        long endTime5S = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime5S = endTime5S - startTime5S;

        long startTime6S = System.currentTimeMillis();
        SelectionSort.SelectionSort(rand5);
        long endTime6S = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime6S = endTime6S - startTime6S;

        //Heap Sort

        long startTime1H = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HeapSort.HeapSort(randH);
        long endTime1H = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime1H = endTime1H - startTime1H;

        long startTime2H = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HeapSort.HeapSort(randH2);
        long endTime2H = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime2H = endTime2H - startTime2H;

        long startTime3H = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HeapSort.HeapSort(randH3);
        long endTime3H = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime3H = endTime3H - startTime3H;

        long startTime4H = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HeapSort.HeapSort(randH4);
        long endTime4H = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime4H = endTime4H - startTime4H;

        long startTime5H = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HeapSort.HeapSort(randH5);
        long endTime5H = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime5H = endTime5H - startTime5H;

        long startTime6H = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HeapSort.HeapSort(randH6);
        long endTime6H = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime6H = endTime6H - startTime6H;

        //Radix Sort

        long startTime1R = System.currentTimeMillis();
        RadixSort.RadixSort(rand);
        long endTime1R = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime1R = endTime1R - startTime1R;

        long startTime2R = System.currentTimeMillis();
        RadixSort.RadixSort(rand1);
        long endTime2R = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime2R = endTime2R - startTime2R;

        long startTime3R = System.currentTimeMillis();
        RadixSort.RadixSort(rand2);
        long endTime3R = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime3R = endTime3R - startTime3R;

        long startTime4R = System.currentTimeMillis();
        RadixSort.RadixSort(rand3);
        long endTime4R = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime4R = endTime4R - startTime4R;

        long startTime5R = System.currentTimeMillis();
        RadixSort.RadixSort(rand4);
        long endTime5R = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime5R = endTime5R - startTime5R;

        long startTime6R = System.currentTimeMillis();
        RadixSort.RadixSort(rand5);
        long endTime6R = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime6R = endTime6R - startTime6R;

        //Quick Sort

        long startTime1Q = System.currentTimeMillis();
        QuickSort.QuickSort(rand);
        long endTime1Q = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime1Q = endTime1Q - startTime1Q;

        long startTime2Q = System.currentTimeMillis();
        QuickSort.QuickSort(rand1);
        long endTime2Q = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime2Q = endTime2Q - startTime2Q;

        long startTime3Q = System.currentTimeMillis();
        QuickSort.QuickSort(rand2);
        long endTime3Q = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime3Q = endTime3Q - startTime3Q;

        long startTime4Q = System.currentTimeMillis();
        QuickSort.QuickSort(rand3);
        long endTime4Q = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime4Q = endTime4Q - startTime4Q;

        long startTime5Q = System.currentTimeMillis();
        QuickSort.QuickSort(rand4);
        long endTime5Q = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime5Q = endTime5Q - startTime5Q;

        long startTime6Q = System.currentTimeMillis();
        QuickSort.QuickSort(rand5);
        long endTime6Q = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime6Q = endTime6Q - startTime6Q;

        //Merge Sort

        long startTime1M = System.currentTimeMillis();
        MergeSort.MergeSort(rand);
        long endTime1M = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime1M = endTime1M - startTime1M;

        long startTime2M = System.currentTimeMillis();
        MergeSort.MergeSort(rand1);
        long endTime2M = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime2M = endTime2M - startTime2M;

        long startTime3M = System.currentTimeMillis();
        MergeSort.MergeSort(rand2);
        long endTime3M = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime3M = endTime3M - startTime3M;

        long startTime4M = System.currentTimeMillis();
        MergeSort.MergeSort(rand3);
        long endTime4M = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime4M = endTime4M - startTime4M;

        long startTime5M = System.currentTimeMillis();
        MergeSort.MergeSort(rand4);
        long endTime5M = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime5M = endTime5M - startTime5M;

        long startTime6M = System.currentTimeMillis();
        MergeSort.MergeSort(rand5);
        long endTime6M = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long executionTime6M = endTime6M - startTime6M;







        //headers for the table
        String[] columns = new String[] {
               "Array Size", "Selection Sort", "Bubble Sort", "Merge Sort", "Quick Sort", "Heap Sort", "Radix Sort"
        };

        //actual data for the table in a 2d array
        Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
                {50000, executionTime1S, executionTime, executionTime1M, executionTime1Q, executionTime1H, executionTime1R},
                {100000, executionTime2S, executionTime1B, executionTime2M, executionTime2Q, executionTime2H, executionTime2R },
                {150000, executionTime3S, executionTime2B, executionTime3M, executionTime3Q, executionTime3H, executionTime3R },
                {200000, executionTime4S, executionTime3B, executionTime4M, executionTime4Q, executionTime4H, executionTime4R },
                {250000, executionTime5S, executionTime4B, executionTime5M, executionTime5Q, executionTime5H, executionTime5R },
                {300000, executionTime6S, executionTime5B, executionTime6M, executionTime6Q, executionTime6H, executionTime6R },


        };
```

Here is the Quick sort.  This line will not work:  QuickSort(list, pivotIndex + 1, last);

```
public class QuickSort {
    public static void QuickSort(int[] list) {
        QuickSort(list, 0, list.length - 1);
    }

    private static void QuickSort(int[] list, int first, int last) {
        if (last > first) {
            int pivotIndex = partition(list, first, last);
            QuickSort(list, first, pivotIndex - 1);
//            QuickSort(list, pivotIndex + 1, last);
        }
    }

    /** Partition the array list[first..last] */
    private static int partition(int[] list, int first, int last) {
        int pivot = list[first]; // Choose the first element as the pivot
        int low = first + 1; // Index for forward search
        int high = last; // Index for backward search

        while (high > low) {
            // Search forward from left
            while (low <= high && list[low] <= pivot)
                low++;

            // Search backward from right
            while (low <= high && list[high] > pivot)
                high--;

            // Swap two elements in the list
            if (high > low) {
                int temp = list[high];
                list[high] = list[low];
                list[low] = temp;
            }
        }

        while (high > first && list[high] >= pivot)
            high--;

        // Swap pivot with list[high]
        if (pivot > list[high]) {
            list[first] = list[high];
            list[high] = pivot;
            return high;
        }
        else {
            return first;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: The line commented out in the Quick Sort will not work:

Answer (score 0):

For the **Insertion Sort** - you've got a stack overflow. A literal one.

You can't use the recursive implementation with these list sizes, as that would mean a stack size linear to the input.

See [What is the maximum depth of the java call stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734108/what-is-the-maximum-depth-of-the-java-call-stack)

You need to implement it iteratively if you want to test lists with such huge numbers of elements.

---

Your main code is screwed. You are only generating two sets of lists which are then already perfectly sorted by the first algorithm each, and the other algorithms then get a sorted list as input.

This is possibly already triggering a stack overflow in your **Quicksort** implementation as well, as Quicksort, when selecting the pivot element not randomly, runs into the absolut worst case behavior when the list is either sorted perfectly in ascending or descending order.

---

If you really want to stress the algorithms (and this **will** cause the stack overflow with Quicksort), don't test only randomized arrays but also the two edge cases of a list which is either already sorted in descending or ascending order.

For most search algorithms, either of these cases triggers the worst case behavior, while the other one usually triggers best case. (Or both are worst case, that can happen as well!)