# Increase the recursive ability of Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, recursion, stack-overflow

I'm writing a java program in Eclipse, and when I try to use recursion it gives this error:
    *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError*
I know that people have probably already asked this question, but every response I've found has been to remove recursion. For what I'm trying to do, recursion is a necessity. There's no other option. I know that the recursive limit can be modified in Enthought Canopy (for python) like this:
    *import sys*
    *sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)*
Is there a way to do this for java in Eclipse? Again, removing recursion is not an option.

UPDATE: I figured out the problem (which was an infinite loop), and the code works now.

Comment: Post the code......

Comment: @Michael Doesn't sound that code would be necessary as OP clearly states he is **not** interested in changing his code to a non-recursive variant.

Comment: @Zabuza - yeah, but an incorrect exit condition could cause the same symptoms.  So it might not help, but it might. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this: [What is the maximum depth of the java call stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734108/what-is-the-maximum-depth-of-the-java-call-stack)

While it is not exactly a duplicate, it also answers your question by explaining how the limit can be changed.

---

Note that **Eclipse** itself has nothing to do with the limit, it is a **Java restriction** and can be increased by **allocating more space** to it.

---

As always with such questions one should note that your code is likely to be inefficient, wrong or maybe has a non-recursive alternative. However you said that you are not interested in such solutions, so I just leave it here as a side note.

Comment: I've discovered that the problem was caused by an infinite loop. The code works now. Thank you for your help!