# Spring Integration Flows: Looking for strategies for avoiding java.lang.StackOverflowError due to recursive flows

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Using `Spring-Integration` version `5.5.18`, I have a `flow` which works well for small sets of inputs but which encounters `java.lang.StackOverflowError` for larger sets due to recursive calls through a `channel` and ending the recursion using a `filter`.  Are there any recommendations for ways of modifying the flow to be less apt to generate `java.lang.StackOverflowError`? (I do know about requesting a larger thread stack for the JVM.) Is there perhaps a way of producing this iteratively with a DSL declaration, rather than recursively? Or perhaps this requires a `MessageHandler` which performs the iteration in `Java` outside of the `Spring-Integration` `Java-DSL`?

An example flow that exhibits the problem could be:

```
package org.example.filter;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.*;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

@Configuration
public class OverflowFlows {

    private static final String CURRENT_ITERATION = "currentIteration";
    private static final String ACCUMULATOR       = "accumulator";
    private static final String RECURSION_CHANNEL = "recurseToBodyValue";

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow callRecursiveFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("createsOverflow")
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerFunction(CURRENT_ITERATION, m -> 0))
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerFunction(ACCUMULATOR, m -> 0))
                .gateway(callRecurseToBodyValueFlow)
                .transform("headers.accumulator")
                .get();
    }

    private final IntegrationFlow callRecurseToBodyValueFlow =
            flow -> flow.channel(RECURSION_CHANNEL);

    @Bean IntegrationFlow recurseToBodyValueFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(RECURSION_CHANNEL)
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression(CURRENT_ITERATION,
                                                     "headers.currentIteration + 1",
                                                     true))
                .filter("headers.currentIteration < payload", DISCARD_RETURNS_CURRENT_MESSAGE)
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression(ACCUMULATOR,
                                                       "headers.accumulator + headers.currentIteration",
                                                       true))
                .channel(RECURSION_CHANNEL)
                .get();
    }

    public static final Consumer<FilterEndpointSpec> DISCARD_RETURNS_CURRENT_MESSAGE = discardReturnsCurrentMessage();

    public static Consumer<FilterEndpointSpec> discardReturnsCurrentMessage() {
        return filterSpec -> filterSpec.discardFlow(IntegrationFlowDefinition::bridge);
    }
}
```

Used in conjunction with the declarations for the `MessageChannel` and the `MessagingGateway`:

```
package org.example.filter;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.MessageChannels;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class OverflowMessageChannels {

    @Bean(name = "createsOverflow")
    public MessageChannel createsOverflow() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

}
```

```
package org.example.filter;

import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Gateway;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;

@MessagingGateway(name = "overflowGateway", defaultReplyTimeout = "20")
public interface OverflowGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "createsOverflow")
    Integer createsOverflow(Integer value);
}
```

The `1000` iteration unit test will cause a stack overflow.

Any pointers on strategies will be appreciated.

```
import org.example.filter.OverflowGateway;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = org.example.filter.ApiConfiguration.class)
public class OverflowTest {

    @Autowired
    OverflowGateway overflowGateway;

    @Test
    public void call_with_one_returns_one() {
        assertThat(overflowGateway.createsOverflow(1), equalTo(sumOfRange(1)));
    }

    @Test
    public void call_with_20_returns_20() {
        assertThat(overflowGateway.createsOverflow(20), equalTo(sumOfRange(20)));
    }

    @Test
    public void call_with_1000_returns_1000() {
        // causes java.lang.StackOverflowError
        assertThat(overflowGateway.createsOverflow(1000), equalTo(sumOfRange(1000)));
    }

    private static int sumOfRange(final int topOfRange) {
        return IntStream.range(1, topOfRange).sum();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has nothing to do with Spring Integration. You simply can get `StackOverflowError` with plain Java: [What is the maximum depth of the java call stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734108/what-is-the-maximum-depth-of-the-java-call-stack). Yes, Spring Integration adds some overhead with its messaging nature via channels and endpoints between them, but logically it doesn't matter: if your logic is recursive in the same thread, you eventually end up with the `StackOverflowError` when add more steps into that loop.

You can break it, though, making that `RECURSION_CHANNEL` as an `ExecutorChannel` instance. This way you push every iteration of that loop into separate thread and call stack becomes not recursive.

Comment: Will changing to an ``ExecutorChannel``` itself be sufficient, that is, without changing the flow?

Comment: I'm a little surprised at the -1 on the question, especially that I gave a complete example.  You say that this isn't a ```Spring-Integration``` problem and I don't agree with that, since the problem is how to implement an iterative process in ```Spring-Integration-DSL``` without encountering StackOverflow.

Comment: Correct. You cannot do anything with the flow because you would have same effect just with plain Java and some recursive method calls.

Comment: That was not mine `-1` on your question. It is indeed correct and has all the required info. Only the problem is outcome which is not tied to any framework: just nature how Java works.

Comment: Within ```Spring-Integration-DSL```, the only mechanism for sequential iteration requires recursion. Moving outside of ```Spring-Integration-DSL```, we can achieve this via simple iteration without recursion and hence no stackoverflow.  The conclusion would seem to be that this is a limitation in the EIP mechanism itself.

Comment: Sure! You can do the logic manually using plain Java API. And yes, sometime it is indeed makes no sense to go the whole EIP if solution could be done with a simple loop. However the original question was about `StackOverflowError` and there is always  limit in Java by itself how many call items can be piled into a stack until it fails. Everything what we do in Spring Integration is just Java at runtime. The DSL works only on configuration phase: it has nothing to do with runtime.

Comment: Sure, the DSL is just there to generate the runtime configuration, I understand that. And, personally, I prefer the XML configuration, which does the same thing, more or less.  But what I was looking for was a DSL-generated solution and I'm finding that I have to code some of this in Java to avoid recursion. So I don't quite agree with your conclusion but I very much appreciate your help so am accepting the response.  Thanks very much.

Comment: The XML configuration for this use-case would lead to the same runtime model. Therefore I don't see your arguments that Java DSL requires more Java to avoid recursion. You would do exactly same adjustments for XML DSL as well.

Comment: I'm posting the form that I've used as a workaround.  Since there is a bit of code in it, posting as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to write an explicit `MessageHandler` that performs the iterations.  This is not the form that I was looking for but it's what I'm going with.

The test method `call_with_1000_returns_1000()` works with this form.

```
package org.example.filter;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class OverflowFlows {

    public static final String CURRENT_ITERATION = "currentIteration";
    public static final String ACCUMULATOR       = "accumulator";

    private final IteratingMessageHandler iteratingMessageHandler;

    public OverflowFlows(final IteratingMessageHandler iteratingMessageHandler) {
        this.iteratingMessageHandler = iteratingMessageHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow callRecursiveFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("createsOverflow")
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerFunction(CURRENT_ITERATION, m -> 0))
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerFunction(ACCUMULATOR, m -> 0))
                .gateway(callIterativeHandler)
                .transform("headers.accumulator")  // put final head value in body
                .get();
    }

    private final IntegrationFlow callIterativeHandler = flow -> flow.handle(iteratingMessageHandler);
}
```

```
package org.example.filter;

import org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import static org.example.filter.OverflowFlows.ACCUMULATOR;
import static org.example.filter.OverflowFlows.CURRENT_ITERATION;

@Component
public class IteratingMessageHandler extends AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler {
    @Override
    protected Object handleRequestMessage(Message<?> message) {
        do {
            final Integer iteration = getIntegerValue(message, CURRENT_ITERATION);
            message = setHeader(message, CURRENT_ITERATION, iteration + 1);
            if (isCurrentIterationBelowPayload(message)) {
                final Integer accumulator = getIntegerValue(message, ACCUMULATOR);
                message = setHeader(message, ACCUMULATOR, accumulator + iteration + 1);
            }
        } while (isCurrentIterationBelowPayload(message));
        return message;
    }

    private static boolean isCurrentIterationBelowPayload(final Message<?> message) {
        return getIntegerValue(message, CURRENT_ITERATION) < (Integer) message.getPayload();
    }

    private static Integer getIntegerValue(final Message<?> message, final String header) {
        return (Integer) message.getHeaders().get(header);
    }

    private static Message<?> setHeader(final Message<?> message, final String header, final Object value) {
        return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message)
                .setHeader(header, value)
                .build();
    }
}
```